# Importing Cython extension obtaining error: "modulenotfounderror: no module named ..."

Tags: python, cython

I've been writing a python wrapper to some fortran code. I'm utilizing Cython to do this. I have my cython extension file titled as "pychiral_wrap1.pyx" with accompanying setupfile:

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import numpy
npy_include_dir = numpy.get_include()

ext_modules = [Extension("chiral", ["pychiral_wrap1.pyx"],
                         include_dirs = [npy_include_dir],
                         extra_objects=["chiral.o", "chiral_wrap1.o"])]

setup(name = 'Chiral Potential Matrix Elements',
      cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
      ext_modules = ext_modules)
```

Where chiral.o and chiral_wrap1.o are object files compiled from fortran. I make my build with the standard command "python setup.py build_ext --inplace".

When I try to import pychiral_wrap1.pyx in

**main.py**

```
import pychiral_wrap1

.....
```

I get the error "modulenotfounderror: no module named pychiral_wrap1". I feel like there's a simple error here, but I can't find it. Is the issue obvious to anyone? Thank you.

Comment: Isn't it just that you're creating a module called `chiral` rather than `pychiral_wrap1`?

Comment: Yup! Thank you, I didn't realize this.